# Why does booting from a DVD fail?

Tags: boot, dvd

I copied the following files to my C drive:

```
boot    ---------- folder
sources ---------- folder
bootmgr ---------- file
```

In an attempt to boot from a windows 10 setup in my internal hard disk drive, I ran the following commands in the windows command prompt:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 1
list partition
select partition 2
active
exit
C:\boot\bootsect.exe
```

All commands worked fine with no error messages. I restarted my computer and then I get a message saying "Your PC needs to be repaired" with error code 0xc0000225. My laptop was running windows 7 before I typed the commands. I inserted a bootable DVD-RW but, despite configuring my BIOS to boot from the DVD, and even selecting to boot from the DVD in the F12 menu, cannot boot from the DVD. My laptop skips the DVD and boots from the hard disk drive, and I get the error message again. Is there any fix for this issue?

Comment: What is on the DVD-RW?

Comment: Those folders alone don’t make anything bootable.  Edit your question.  Comments that contain information, that should be in the question, will be ignored.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the DVD-RW contains the windows 7 setup files.